# CAML QUERY does not work in IE11 when searching by content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, caml-query, caml

I've this code below:

```
function BuscarDocumentosHoje(Departamento,NivelAutorizacao,NumeroColaborador,todayfinal){
    var restUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/Negocio/Precario/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('1. Capítulo 1 - Preçário CEMG')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=" + "{\"ViewXml\":\"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>Capítulo 1 - Preçário Documentos</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='DataVigor_Precario' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>"+todayfinal+"</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>\"}";

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: restUrl,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },

        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

When I remove this part of the code, the caml query works

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>Capítulo 1 - Preçário Documentos</Value></Eq>
```

I tested it in google chrome and it works correctly but in IE it does not.
Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the special characters and it already worked.